# How can I read a CSS Variable in NativeScript using JavaScript

Tags: nativescript-vue

I use CSS Variables in my NativeScript-Vue App, as described in the [official documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#using-css-variables). I am looking for a way to read the value of a variable using JavaScript. Since there is no real browser engine, the [established way](https://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-javascript) doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much documentation, but there actually is a method mentioned in the API documentation: [`Style.getCssVariable(name)`](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_styling_style_.style#getcssvariable). Using this method you can read CSS Variables, defined in the `app.[s]css` like this:

```js
const color = this.$root.nativeView.style.getCssVariable('--color-primary')
console.log(color); // e.g. '#FF0000'
```

I would have expected this to also work on `this.$el`, but for some reason, this will only return `null` in my setup, allthough the variables are in the global scope and available in the style of the very same component. Maybe someone else can clarify, why this is.

Answer (score -1):

in app.css

```
.main{
    --primary: #02AC46;
    --secondary: #ED7200;
}
```

in any .css

```
background-color: var(--primary);
```

Comment: This is correct, but the actual question was how to read CSS Variables using JavaScript.